# Get roxygen details for a function

Tags: r, roxygen2

Is there a function that gets the roxygen details for a given function?

For example, if my function was

```
#' Negate a number
#' @param x some number
#' @output -x negation of input
fun <- function(x) -x
```

I'd like to do this:

```
info <- get_roxygen_info(fun) # <- this is made up for illustration

> info
> list(description = 'Negate a number', param = 'x some number', output = '-x negation of input')
```

The purpose is to put all the functions in a script(s) into a table with its descriptions.  I can already partially do this using a combination of `lsf.str()` to get the function names and `formals` to get function arguments.  Worst case is parsing the script as text which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: `utils:::.getHelpFile(help('mean')) |> str()`

Comment: That didn't work for me 
`> utils:::.getHelpFile(help('mean')) |> str()
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'str': invalid 'description' argument`

Comment: works fine for me. `str` is not important to the answer, it just shows you that the object is broken up into the list parts

Comment: I think `str` is not the problem, my utils version is 4.1.1 `> utils:::.getHelpFile(help('mean'))
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument`

Answer (score 2):

You can't necessarily do that:  not all Roxygen tags are kept when the file is parsed.  If you have access to the source file you can do it, and you might be able to find the source file from the function.

For example, if I put your sample into `sample.R` and source it with the default `keep.source=TRUE`, I can get the filename, and then use Roxygen to parse that file:

```
library(roxygen2)

filename <- getSrcFilename(fun, full.names = TRUE)

parsed <- parse_file(filename)

thisfn <- which(sapply(parsed, function(block) block$line == getSrcLocation(fun, "line") ))

parsed[[thisfn]]
```

That produces this output:

```
> parsed[[thisfn]]
<roxy_block> [sample.R:4]
  $tag
    [line:  1] @title 'Negate a number' {parsed}
    [line:  2] @param 'x some number' {parsed}
    [line:  4] @usage '<generated>' {parsed}
    [line:  4] @.formals '<generated>' {parsed}
    [line:  4] @backref '<generated>' {parsed}
  $call   fun <- function(x) -x
  $object <function> 
    $topic fun
    $alias fun
Warning message:
[sample.R:3] @output is not a known tag
```

I'll leave it to you to extract the parts you want.

But I'll give the usual advice:  if your script is long enough that you would need a table of contents for it, why not put it in a small package?  Then R will do all the work of organizing the documentation for you.